# Allow impersonation users to login to Exchange Server by EWS Managed API 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, configuration, exchangewebservices

I have an `ASP .Net Application` hosted on `Windows Server 2016` `IIS 10`. `Impersonation` and `Windows Authentication` are enabled.

I wish a logged in Active Directory users to perform some actions related to their own mailboxes without any additional logins (I mean without entering username/password).

Is it possible and what configuration changes should be done over the `Exchange Server`, `Active Directory` users and the server where the app is hosted?

There is how I use `EWS Managed  API`:

```
using (var context = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
{
    string mailbox = "user@domain.com"
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(mailbox);
    service.Url = new Uri(serverAddress);
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    var rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, mailbox));
}
```

In that case with `AutodiscoverUrl` I have an error: `The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.`
When I try to avoid `AutodiscoverUrl`, like this:

```
using (var context = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
{
    string serverAddress = "https://domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
    string mailbox = "user@domain.com"
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.Url = new Uri(serverAddress);
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    var rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, mailbox));
}
```

I also meet the error: `The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

Could you, please, recommend how to configure these servers to let them communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow kerberos delegation have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/11/05/ews-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication-and-impersonation/ which has a sample and explanation of what needs to be done.

Comment: In this example authorization with credentials is used to get access to the service. (at default.aspx.cs). Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem I've faced

Comment: You need to read through the post (not just look at the example) it covers both the credentials and impersonation the important thing is allowing delegation and using Kerberos. The thing to understand is kerberos must be used between client and the IIS (not IIS to EWS), IIS then will be able to delegate the credentials (made to it) and use those to make the connection to EWS (if configured correctly)